# How to make a Button in iOS control centre for my app in React Native Expo?

Tags: ios, react-native, mobile, expo, control-center

I want to make a button displayed in control centre on ios devices to make a shortcut for a function in my app. I don't know where to start to make this button so is there any library or forum to create an idea.